# Add more instances to Selenium Docker

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have downloaded Selenium Grid from a Docker compose, following the [documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#selenium-grid-hub-and-nodes). Now, I have all the images up and running.

[image]

Also, the UI is working.

[image]

For each browser, I have only one instance. I want to increment the number of instances for each browser. So, I can run parallel tests. I can't find the way to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the environment variable `SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS` (former `NODE_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS`) for the node you would like to set the concurrency for.. For example:

```yaml
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-beta-1-20210215
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=5
    ports:
   

   - "6900:5900
```

So your UI would then look like:

[image]

**P.S.** - Here you can find the complete guide to [Selenium Grid 4 configuration flags](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_grid_4_complete_guide_to_configuration_flags).